# Intercept ALL dependencies with Castle Dynamic Proxy

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Castle Dynamic Proxy interceptor in my code (for logging purpose). I know how to set the interceptor on a dependency, like that:

```
      container.Register(Component.For<MyService>().
           Interceptors<LoggerInterceptor>());
```

But how can i set this interceptor to **ALL** my dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do any registration of your components you can add a handler that will add your interceptor to every component:

```
        container.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += (key, handler) =>
        {
            handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(LoggingInterceptor)));
        };
```

Comment: Did this assist?

Answer (score 1):

Use convention registration:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                          .Pick()
                          .WithService.Self()
                          .Configure(r => r.Interceptors<LoggerInterceptor>()));
```

Comment: I don't want to do that because I already registered all my dependencies. Also I registered different depenencies in different ways (some of them singletons some of them transients some of them with names etc.) so I dont want to use convention and loose all my work here.